# SOLR - DataImportHandler - how to map multiple objects inside one list of json objects

Tags: solr, dih

I am new to SOLR,I am trying to index oracle DB query results using SOLR. I have written config.xml and added indexes in schema.xml as well.

I have multiple queries as sub-entities(with child=true) in my config.xml file. Many of the queries are returning multiple rows. For example I have one entity as

```
<entity name="example_subentity" child="true" query="SELECT A,B from table_temp">
    <field column="A" name="a" />
    <field column="B" name="b" />
</entity>
```

which returns output as

```
"response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "unique_key":"4493234234",
        "_version_":1560479076226957312,
        "_childDocuments_":[
        {
          "a" : "value_a_1",
          "b" : "value_b_1",
        },
        {
          "a" : "value_a_2",
          "b" : "value_b_2",
        }]
      }]}
```

what I am trying to achieve here is, something like

```
 "_childDocuments_":[ 
      {"table_temp_response" :[
        {
          "a" : "value_a_1",
          "b" : "value_b_1",
        },
        {
          "a" : "value_a_2",
          "b" : "value_b_2",
        }]
        }]
```

Can anyone guide me, how I can get this kind of output using DIH?

**Just a update I am looking for a server side solution, I can do this using java or SOLRJ in client side. But I have multiple client which are going to consume SOLR query response.**

Answer (score 0):

if you use Solrj

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < docList.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(docList.get(i));
            jArray.put(json);
        }
```

> > >

```
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = objs.getJSONObject(i);
            obj.getString("a"));
```

Comment: Thanks for response, I think we can modify solr response in java. But is there any way we can modify config.xml file so that after query we should get structured response even if any number of clients making that query?

Comment: Is there a way to do this in server side, I am looking for a scalable way. So that multiple client can use solr here.